# Can't save python script in IDLE with 2.7.11/12

Tags: python, save, python-idle

I've downloaded IDLE in mint and for some reason I can't save. I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1540, in __call__
 return self.func(*args)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/EditorWindow.py", line 1002, in close
 reply = self.maybesave()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/EditorWindow.py", line 999, in maybesave
 return self.io.maybesave()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/IOBinding.py", line 331, in maybesave
self.save(None)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/IOBinding.py", line 345, in save
if self.writefile(self.filename):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/IOBinding.py", line 378, in writefile
chars = self.encode(self.text.get("1.0", "end-1c"))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/IOBinding.py", line 450, in encode
dialog = EncodingMessage(self.editwin.top, enc)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/IOBinding.py", line 76, in __init__
self.root = top = Toplevel(master)
NameError: global name 'Toplevel' is not defined
```

What's going on? IDLE seems great but without saving it's useless =(

**UPDATE:** IDLE is saving normally now due to an update in mint... (I think so... because I'm still using Python 2.7.12)

Comment: Wait, you downloaded IDLE? It didn't come with your Python distribution?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Some linux distributors put tkinter/IDLE/turtle in a separate and optional package.

Comment: This is a regression in 2.7.11 fixed in 2.7.13.